# Ударение в фамилии Цариценская

Tags: имена-собственные

Скажите, пожалуйста, где нужно поставить ударение в фамилии ЦарИценская? Мы ставим на И, но нам говорят, если бы после второй Ц была бы Ы, то да, ударение на И, но т к после Ц, идет Е значит ударение на Е, ЦарицЕнская.

Answer (score 1):

О фамилиях уже говорилось. Как правильно произносится фамилия, могут сказать только носители этой самой фамилии. По идее фамилия Цариценская уже образована с нарушением правил русского языка: должно быть Царицынская. "Ошибка" в написании могла появиться на каком угодно этапе существования этого имени собственного (например, ошибку допустил какой-нибудь письмоводитель по причине свое неграмотности).Но, повторяю, какие-либо правила здесь весьма условны. Тем более, когда речь идет об ударении в фамилии.

Answer (score 0):

Всё было бы так, не будь фамилия достаточно распространённой и известной. Вариант ЦарицЕнская вполне возможен, если не сказать предпочтетелен. Поэтому лучше уточнить у носителей, тут я согласен.